# Global GPU quota needed but can't request increase

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, gpu, gae-quotas, google-dl-platform

I'm trying to use GCloud's deep learning VM image. My request for 8 Tesla K80s was approved. But when I try to create an instance with even a single GPU, I get an error saying the Global GPU limit of 0 is exceeded.

The error statement in specific:
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource: - Quota 'GPUS_ALL_REGIONS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 globally.

The code I wrote to create the VM is this:

```
export IMAGE_FAMILY="tf-latest-cu92"

export ZONE="us-west1-b"

export INSTANCE_NAME="my-new-instance"

export INSTANCE_TYPE="n1-standard-8"

gcloud compute instances create $INSTANCE_NAME \
    --zone=$ZONE \
    --image-family=$IMAGE_FAMILY \
    --image-project=deeplearning-platform-release \
    --maintenance-policy=TERMINATE \
    --accelerator="type=nvidia-tesla-k80,count=1" \
    --machine-type=$INSTANCE_TYPE \
    --boot-disk-size=120GB \
    --metadata="install-nvidia-driver=True"
```

This code snippet is drawn from:
https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/docs/quickstart-cli

Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same thing happen a while ago. You have to increase the Tesla K80 quota as well as a global quota called `GPUS_ALL_REGIONS`. I'm not sure how to do this from the command line, but you can do it through the web console by going into your IAM settings, selecting "Quotas" from the side bar. In the dropdown labeled "Metric", deselect everything except for "GPUs (all regions)". You will now need to increase this quota to 8 as well. Once it is approved, you will be able to use all of your GPUs.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE 2022**:

Here is how to do it in the 2022 Gcloud UI:

Simply write: GPUS_ALL_REGION in the filter input and then edit the selected quota.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although this was already answered by @Alex Krantz, here is a screenshot to the corresponding UI mask in the Gcloud UI.
You can nativagate to this page through "IAM & Admin", then "Quotas".

[image]